# What is the proper way to set up a domain class MongoDB/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb

I am currently making a WPF application and am now ready to add a mongo database, however I can't seem to find the best process to do this with. right now I am doing it like so:

MongoManagment.cs:

```
namespace MoneyManagment
{
    class MongoManagment
    {
        public void Connect()
        {
            String connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
            MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("MoneyManagment"); //Connect to the database
            MongoCollection<Users> _users = database.GetCollection<Users>("user"); // "user" is the collection name, "Users" is the domain class

        }
    }

   public class Users
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then I try to access the data from the domain class in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace MoneyManagment
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (Users user in _users.FindAll())
            {
                //do something with users data here
            }
        }
    }
```

And I get an error here that VS can not access `_users`, which to an extent makes sense, the problem is though, I have tried a plethora of different ways to make that accessible and it's just not working which leads me to believe that there is a better way to go about this. Any ideas?

Comment: where did you actually instantiate the `_users` variable? usually a variable that starts with _ is indicating that it's private, not accessible to the entire application stack? either way, the `MainWindow` class in your example doesn't hold any reference to the variable.

Comment: @AndrewCounts right, it doesnt. I have tried different ways of referenceing it and none have worked, so is there a better way to go about this than what im trying to do? how is it usually done? im new to c# and mongo...

Comment: your declaration doesn't make sense in C# terms at all.  what you are showing is a `_users` variable that is declared in the Scope of the `Connect` Function of the `MongoManagement` Class, but trying to access it from a totally different Class.  take a read through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx, regarding Variables and Scope (old article, mostly VB, but the concepts are valid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need the variable that you want to access to be publicly visible.

```
public class MongoManagment
{
    public MongoCollection<Users> MongoUsers {get; set;}

    public void Connect()
    {
        ....
        this.MongoUsers = database.GetCollection<Users>("user");
    }
```

then, you need to reference the object in the external class:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        ....
        MongoManagement mm = new MongoManagement();
        mm.Connect();
        foreach (Users user in mm.MongoUsers.FindAll())
        {
            //do something with users data here
        }
```

**note** this is a very simplistic example, and you may not want a copy of `MongoManagment` for every window, etc.  You will still want to spend a bit of time exploring the concepts of variable lifecycles, scope....